# Ionic v1 - HTTPS API call is not working in real device

Tags: android, android-emulator, iis-8, self-signed, ionic-v1

Previously we were using HTTP for our REST API and had no issues. But, we changed our REST API server to run with **HTTPS with self-signed certificate in IIS** and now we have some issues.

When we try to run the mobile app in Android Emulator, it works correctly. But, when we tried to run in real mobile device, it does not work.

How can I make this work with a real Android device?

***To whomsoever it may concern:***

- Plugin **cordova-plugin-ionic-webview** is used
- Plugin **cordova-plugin-whitelist** is used

**Config.xml**

```
...
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I was required to **add inbound rule** in **Windows Firewall for the Port 443**.

But the following links may help others if the issue is other than Firewall port.

**Helpful Links:**

- [REST API not working on Android Device](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/rest-api-call-not-working-on-android-device/23418)
- [Cordova Plugin Whitelist - Content Security Policy](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist#content-security-policy)
- [iOS 10 Compatibility CSP](http://www.qed42.com/blog/ionic-iOS10-compatibility-csp)
- [Cordova Security Whitelist](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/cordova-security-whitlists/)